Apache2 - protect only directory but not subdirectory
I'm trying to host a webserver with Apache2 on Debian 12. 
I want to limit access to webserver/dir1 with a password promt. This already works. 
My issue is, that webserver/dir1/subdir1 has to be available to multiple people.
Therefore I want them to access this site without any password while webserver/dir1 is still protected.  Sadly the password protection works for webserver/dir1 and webserver/dir1/subdir1. But I want everyone to access webserver/dir1/subdir1 without a password.
This is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf (I'm not using any .htaccess-files):
<VirtualHost *:80>
         ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
         DocumentRoot /var/www/html
 
         ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
         CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
 
         <Directory "/var/www/html/dir1">
                 AuthType Basic
                 AuthName "Only for members"
                 AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                 Require valid-user
         </Directory>
         <Directory "/var/www/html/dir1/subdir1">
                 Satisfy any
                 Order Allow,Deny
                 Allow from all
                 Require all granted
         </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>

Thanks in advance for your help!

This is not possible in a direct manner, that simply is how such protection works: it protects all paths underneath the configured base path. The process follows the path from root to whatever resource has been requested, on that way it has to pass the dir1 folder which is protected. You will have to find a way to publish that subfolder under a different path, maybe by means of a link or a loopback mount in the server side file system or even a separate virtual host inside the apache http server.

I'd say just create a /var/www/html/dir2 and put symlinks to ../dir1/subdir1 named /dir2/dir1 -- as I suspect subdir1 is the same in all your dir1. Then, in 00-default.conf you add Options +FollowSymLinks in a new section you create for dir2 (it might be a Location section, though).
